# Using Auto Layouts while 4 screen app running in 3.5 screen

Tags: iphone, ios, autolayout

I developed a app for iPhone5 i enabled Use Auto Layouts.I have taken vertical space 40 for each button to its another button . when i run this app on iPhone4s the last button is not appeared.I.How to decrease vertical spacing while it is running in 4s.enter image description here

[image: This is how it looks in iphone 4s]

Comment: Come up with a better set of constraints that don't rely on fixed numbers.

Comment: You have to set `Constraints` for every button properly.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist Agreed. Or, more accurately, you want constraints that don't rely on number of pixels/points. It's fine to have, for example, centerY constraints that employ a fixed `multiplier` (e.g. a percentage of the super view's centerY) because that works regardless of screen height, but you want to avoid using a fixed `constant` values.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a spacer view between each button. That way you can use a variable size of the space that depends on the height of the screen.

Something like this...

```
@"V:|[_spacer1][_button1][_spacer2(==_spacer1)][_button2][_spacer3(==spacer1)][_button3]...[_lastSpacer(==spacer1)]|"
```

This will then layout all the buttons with equal spaces between them. But the space between will change depending on the height of the screen.

Comment: thanks for the reply.Is there any way of decreasing vertical space constraint by coding

Comment: Why? This will work and is a lot easier as you don't have to calculate anything. For instance, where did the number 40 come from? If you had to use a calculator or do maths then you're using AutoLayout wrong.

Comment: N.B. You can make the spacer views clear so they are not visible. You're just using them for layout.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to do this in code, you have to add some hidden "spacer" views in between your buttons with "equal height" constraints and no explicit height. They will expand/contract as appropriate to space the buttons out correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

While you can use clear/hidden `UIView` objects as spacers, as others have described, that's not necessary. You can also create constraints programmatically, evenly spacing them with the judicious use of `multiplier` values supplied to the [`constraintWithItem`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/NSLayoutConstraint/NSLayoutConstraint.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSLayoutConstraint/constraintWithItem%3aattribute%3arelatedBy%3atoItem%3aattribute%3amultiplier%3aconstant%3a) method. For example, if you have an array of `UIButton` objects, you can vertically space them with:

```
[buttons enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:obj
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                         multiplier:2.0 * (idx + 1.0)/([buttons count] + 1.0)
                                                           constant:0.0]];
}];
```